# getting data out of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im sort of new to this, but I was wondering how I can grab the data (ie:shapeID) from this function and pass it on to other functions making it a global variable.

```
$('.shapes li').click(function(shapeId){
    var shapeId = $(this).find('a').attr('id');
    var shapeImg = $(this).find('img');
    step2.find('div.wrapper').attr('id', shapeId);
    shapeImg.clone().appendTo('#step2 .model', '#results .model');
    step1.fadeOut('500',shownext);
    step2.find('.waist_box').show();
    step2.find('.hotspots #waist').addClass('active');
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a callback:

```
$('.shapes li').click(function(){
    var shapeId = $(this).find('a').attr('id');
    setShapeID(shapeID);
    var shapeImg = $(this).find('img');
    step2.find('div.wrapper').attr('id', shapeId);
    shapeImg.clone().appendTo('#step2 .model', '#results .model');
    step1.fadeOut('500',shownext);
    step2.find('.waist_box').show();
    step2.find('.hotspots #waist').addClass('active');
});

function setShapeID(id){
   shapeID = id; //<<in global namespace
}
```

Then in any other function if you want to use it check if it is defined:

```
if(shapeID !== undefined){
    //use it!
}
```

---

The above is under assumption that you want to pollute the global namespace.

If you do not want to do that, then you can use an object to hold your id:

```
var IDs = {
    shape: null
}

$('.shapes li').click(function(){
    var shapeId = $(this).find('a').attr('id');
    IDs.shape = shapeID; //<<set the shapeID
    var shapeImg = $(this).find('img');
    step2.find('div.wrapper').attr('id', shapeId);
    shapeImg.clone().appendTo('#step2 .model', '#results .model');
    step1.fadeOut('500',shownext);
    step2.find('.waist_box').show();
    step2.find('.hotspots #waist').addClass('active');
});
```

Then outside you can use the `shapeID` easily by doing `IDs.shape`

Comment: @PaulPRO -- although mine did not have the same issue as the others :-P. mine was not doing the same thing, so mine **always** worked :-P

Comment: lol good point, I didn't really look carefully to see what you were doing lol, just read that you fixed it below :) Still your answer works, and it probably is better to not store an Event object in a variable called shapeId haha

Comment: @Neal this is so awesome. Exactly what I was looking for. Im trying to take the data from all my functions and merge them into a json array :D

Answer (score 4):

Just declare `shapeId` outside of the function:

```
var shapeId = null;

$('.shapes li').click(function(){
    shapeId = $(this).find('a').attr('id');
    var shapeImg = $(this).find('img');
    step2.find('div.wrapper').attr('id', shapeId);
    shapeImg.clone().appendTo('#step2 .model', '#results .model');
    step1.fadeOut('500',shownext);
    step2.find('.waist_box').show();
    step2.find('.hotspots #waist').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: -1 because someone upvoted it even though it doesn't work since you still create a local copy of shapeId in the function arguments.

Comment: @PaulPRO -- no you don't, why do you think that? you are not re-declaring `var shapeID`

Comment: @Neal, Try running this short code in a console: `var x = 12; (function(x){ x = 10;})(); alert(x);` It alerts 12. The inner function doesn't change the global x when it's declared locally. That's exactly what happens here. See my answer below...

Comment: @PaulPro  -- you are right, still doesnt need a `-1` none of us noticed that in the function call, that is an odd call.

Comment: I said you are right! the OP wrote it wrong. i fixed my answer.

Comment: @Neal I know, I only downvoted to offset the upvote since it doesn't work the upvotes could be misleading. I didn't downvote any other answers with the same problem which didn't get upvotes.

Comment: @Neal It's also easy to remove a -1 if the answer is edited so that it works.

Comment: @FishBasket Changed -1 to a +1 :)

Comment: Didn't notice the argument to the handler function. That's what I get for copy-pasting so haphazardly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access ShareId outside of your function just declare it outside of the function:

```
var shapeId;
$('.shapes li').click(function(shapeId){
    shapeId = $(this).find('a').attr('id');
    var shapeImg = $(this).find('img');
    step2.find('div.wrapper').attr('id', shapeId);
    shapeImg.clone().appendTo('#step2 .model', '#results .model');
    step1.fadeOut('500',shownext);
    step2.find('.waist_box').show();
    step2.find('.hotspots #waist').addClass('active');
});

function whatever(){
   alert(shapeId);
}
```

Comment: `shareID`? don't you mean `shapeID`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making it a real global variable perhaps you can wrap it in an anonymous function?

```
(function($) {
  var shapeId;
  $('.shapes li').click(function(){
    shapeId = $(this).find('a').attr('id');
    var shapeImg = $(this).find('img');
    step2.find('div.wrapper').attr('id', shapeId);
    shapeImg.clone().appendTo('#step2 .model', '#results .model');
    step1.fadeOut('500',shownext);
    step2.find('.waist_box').show();
    step2.find('.hotspots #waist').addClass('active');

    myfunction();
  });

  function myfunction()
  {
      console.log(shapeId);
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Or call the function from within the current function:

```
  $('.shapes li').click(function(){
    var shapeId = $(this).find('a').attr('id');
    var shapeImg = $(this).find('img');
    step2.find('div.wrapper').attr('id', shapeId);
    shapeImg.clone().appendTo('#step2 .model', '#results .model');
    step1.fadeOut('500',shownext);
    step2.find('.waist_box').show();
    step2.find('.hotspots #waist').addClass('active');

    myfunction(shapeId);
  });

  function myfunction(theId)
  {
    console.log(theId);
  }
```

Comment: in that second one you are still creating the global variable!

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have it right except for it to work you also have to remove shapeId from your function arguments list. It doesn't make any sense there anyways since it just assigns an `Event` object to it and then you overwrite it write away.

Change:

```
$('.shapes li').click(function(shapeId){
    var shapeId = $(this).find('a').attr('id');
```

To:

```
var shapeId; // shapeId in outer scope
$('.shapes li').click(function(){
    shapeId = $(this).find('a').attr('id');
```